# How to create selector (or plugin) to access TdxBarButton that sits on TdxBar - for RPA-automation of Delphi 6 application?

Tags: delphi, automated-tests, devexpress, rpa, devexpress-windows-ui

I am trying to automate Delphi 6 application that uses DevExpress components, specifically TdxBar and TdxBarButtons that are available on popup menus. I am using OpenRPA, where I am using 'Get Element' activity. It has 'Open selector' tools which allows to select any Windows UI (and other) elements from any visible program. The 'Open selector' tool is very handy, but my application has TdxBar component with the something-like-buttons which open (popup)-menus which in turn have TdxBarButtons and the 'Open selector' sees the entire TdxBar component as one element, it can not select separate parts of TdxBar and it doesn't see the components which act as active elements to open popupmenu.

So - how to create selector for TdxBar subcomponents or even for TdxBarButtons that are revealed from TdxBar menu dialogs?

Maybe I can write some OpenRPA plugin that receives some Windows area and that explores further this area and finds Windows acreas that are ignored by the standard OpenRA tools?

How other suites (commercial RPA automation suites) is dealing with TdxBar and TdxBarButton?

I guess, that the best practice today is to develop programs than can be automated (one is advised to ship only products that are tested and can be tested by RPA-automation tools).

**Additional information**:

DevExpress does not acknowledge any non-standard behavior https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q261746/how-to-click-a-tdxbarbutton-in-testcomplete

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-Questions/FindAll-by-alternative-properties/m-p/238553 gives some clarification how automation plugin could work - there is not need to detect Windows UI button specifically - there may be FindAll Windows function that is able to find any area on the Windows Desktop.

OpenRPA has guidelines for plugin creation https://openrpa.openrpa.dk/pages/plugin-model

Currently this information have not solved my problem yet, however I am still reading it.

Comment: Did you read how some of the other Developer Express VCL controls are supported along with supported versions? Bottom table on this page: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/general-info/supported-technologies/controls/devexpress.html then follow some of the links for support details.